# LINQ to select a column with max date from a group

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have following table in which I can have multiple time stamps for a single name.
I want to get the name (distinct) with max time stamp.

```
Id  Name    TimeStamp
66  Name1   19/10/2017
67  Name1   20/10/2017
68  Name1   21/10/2017
69  Name2   19/10/2017
70  Name2   20/10/2017
71  Name2   21/10/2017
72  Name2   22/10/2017
73  Name3   19/10/2017
74  Name3   20/10/2017
75  Name3   21/10/2017
```

I am able to do group by,now need to select the element with max value from that group.

```
 var tempResult = data.GroupBy(x => x.Name);
```

I tried doing this , nut it only selected the date time, but I need the complete item:

```
foreach (var item in tempResult)
            {
                var maxItem = item.Max(x=>x.StartTime);

            }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
var result = from d in data
    group d by d.Name into g
    select new { Name = g.Key, MaxDate = g.Max(s => s.StartTime) }
```

Or if you do not like query syntax then:

```
data.GroupBy(i => i.Name).Select(g => new
{
    Name = g.Key,
    MaxDate = g.Max(row => row.StartTime)
});
```

Comment: Looks solid and clean

Comment: what if I want to get the Id as well?

Comment: @KMR Simply Group by multiple things: `group d by new { d.Id, d.Name }` and then select it `select new { Name = g.Key.Name, Id = g.Key.Id // ect. }`

Answer (score 4):

@CodingYoshi's answer is enough if you just need Name and TimeStamp.
If you want to select all other properties (full object) you can use this.

```
    var tempResult = data.GroupBy(x => x.Name)
        .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(y => y.TimeStamp).FirstOrDefault());
```

if you like query form then this

```
    var tempResult2 = from x in data
                      group x by x.Name into g
                      select g.OrderByDescending(y => y.TimeStamp).FirstOrDefault();
```

Here in your case you can access all the properties (including ID).